# CollectionAssert data from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, nunit

For some reason, I am unable to use `CollectionAssert` with NUnit and Entity Framework. I have a list of expected results (a customer in this case) and the collection returned from EF.

When I try to check the results match, instead of getting the type I expected from EF I instead get something called `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies`.

This is my unit test:

```
var expectedSearchResult = new SearchResult()
{
    FoundCustomers = new List<Customer>() {
        new Customer
        {
            FirstName = "Test", LastName = "Test", City = "Test", Country = "test", Phone = "00000000000" }
        }
};
var result = searchService.GeneralSearch("Test");
// Here I am expecting exactly one customer in result.FoundCustomers
// but I get a DynamicProxy instead
CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedSearchResult.FoundCustomers, result.FoundCustomers);
```

Is NUnit somehow incompatible with Entity Framework? What am I missing?

Comment: You should know about the function of [dynamic proxies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592886.aspx) if you work with EF.

Comment: Even then, you compare two different objects (`new Customer` and the one from EF). CollectionAssert.AreEqual will never pass, unless you provide a comparer.

Comment: The one from EF and the new Customer here are the same type though

Comment: You can make many different objects of the same type. Identical property values doesn't make them "equal".

Comment: How should I proceed from here then? Casting from the proxy?

Comment: Does Customer define Equals?